# strncmp() implementation optimisation

Tags: c, string, optimization

If I have an implementation of `strncmp()` that checks whether two strings are the same, can I optimise it significantly by doing something like this:

```
if (str1 == str2) {
    return true;
} else {
    /* Do real comparison here */
}
```

Note that as I am implementing something different to the C library so these are non-standard, this is on purpose.

The logic behind this is: if the two strings actually point to the same location, they must be identical. This could save a lot of checking if the strings are long.

Comment: But if they didn't point to the same location then you have slowed your code down.  Is your function likely to be called with two pointers to the same location?

Comment: It's in a standard library, so not sure. Depends on the calling program.

Comment: If you're writing a library then don't force the users to incur any penalties. The user can perform this test before calling the library function if their code is likely to be calling it with two identical pointers.

Comment: I can't think of a single time I've called strcmp or strncmp where both parameters could have been equal.

Comment: I don't know what your question is. What is it? And you could check but in that case you should actually warn the caller, like *There is a bug in your code, you are calling `strncmp()` and both parameters point to the same place*. And it seems that the bug is in your code, because you say that it improved performance. So check the code that is doing this and fix it.

Comment: @iharob I didn't say that that improved performance. I asked if it /could/ improve performance.

Comment: It could, but it would hide a bug in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it.

Whether it actually speeds your application up will depend on your application's behavior.

- If "equal" strings are frequently different pointers OR if the strings you are comparing are rarely "equal", then your optimization could actually slow down your application.
- If you change your application to (for example) canonicalize the strings so that "equal" strings always have the same pointer value, then the overheads of doing that<sup>1</sup> could outweigh the savings.

---

<sup>1 - For example, by building a giant hash table of strings that have been seen already.  Caution: beware of memory leaks!</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For each string, you can store some lightweight hash of this string, int-size. so, you can compare hashes first, and if they equals - compare strings.

Light function for hashing string:

```
uint32_t hash(const char *s) {
  uint32_t rc = 0x1F351F35; // Barker code 2x
  while(*s)
    rc = ((rc << 5) | (rc >> (32 - 5))) + *s++;
  return rc;
}
```

Comment: Just a small syntax error that I noticed: your `while(*s)` has no closing brace.

Comment: Can't edit question because ``edits must be at least 6 characters''.

Comment: I'm not convinced that will make `strncmp()` faster.  Hashing each string guarantees traversing the entire length of both strings at least once, and fully twice each for equal strings.  Normal `strncmp()` will traverse each string at most once each and each traversal will be shortened should a difference be found.